# Implicitly capture const variable in a template lambda with no capture-default specified

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following code:

```
auto f() {
  const auto x = 1;
  return [] (auto) { return x; };
}
```

[**GCC and MSVC compiles fine but Clang rejected it**](https://godbolt.org/z/zhTYo5). Which compiler should I trust? Is that some compiler extension that Clang does not implement yet or Is it just a Clang bug?

Comment: *A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing it if the variable
 has const non-volatile integral or enumeration type and has been initialized with a constant expression* [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: fyi - small change and it compiles `return [] (auto y) { return x + y; };`  Maybe add `[language-lawyer]` ?

Comment: Another thing, why is `gcc` throwing warning (`variable 'x' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]`) even when it is being used inside lambda?

Comment: Possibly related: [#20289](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20289)

Comment: Even stranger clang compiles `return [] (auto) { return +x; };`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a clang bug.

The rule we have is [[basic.def.odr]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#9):

> A local entity is odr-usable in a scope if:
>
> - either the local entity is not *this, or an enclosing class or non-lambda function parameter scope exists and, if the innermost such scope is a function parameter scope, it corresponds to a non-static member function, and
> - for each intervening scope ([basic.scope.scope]) between the point at which the entity is introduced and the scope (where *this is considered to be introduced within the innermost enclosing class or non-lambda function definition scope), either:
>
>   - the intervening scope is a block scope, or
>   - the intervening scope is the function parameter scope of a lambda-expression that has a simple-capture naming the entity or has a capture-default, and the block scope of the lambda-expression is also an intervening scope.
>
> If a local entity is odr-used in a scope in which it is not odr-usable, the program is ill-formed.

In our example:

```cpp
auto f() {
  const auto x = 1;
  return [] (auto) { return x; };
}
```

`x` is not odr-usable in the lambda body because of the intervening scope that does not capture `x` (neither a simple-capture nor a capture-default).

So, it's not odr-usable. But is it odr-used? No, from [[basic.def.odr]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4):

> A variable is named by an expression if the expression is an id-expression that denotes it. A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `E` is odr-used by `E` unless
>
> - `x` is a reference that is usable in constant expressions ([expr.const]), or
> - `x` is a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions and has no mutable subobjects, and `E` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression of non-volatile-qualified non-class type to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([conv.lval]) is applied, or
> - `x` is a variable of non-reference type, and `E` is an element of the set of potential results of a discarded-value expression ([expr.prop]) to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied.

The second bullet applies (and conveniently our variable is even named `x`!) `x` is usable in constant expressions because it's a constant integral type and `E` is an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion here.

So `x` is not odr-usable, but also not odr-used, so there's no problem here.

---

Indeed, we even have this example in [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#7):

```cpp
void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {});         // #1
void f(const int&, const int (&)[1]);       // #2
void test() {
  const int x = 17;
  auto g = [](auto a) {
    f(x);                       // OK: calls #1, does not capture x
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yep, Clang bug.

The applicable rule is from [[basic.def.odr]/9](https://wg21.link/basic.def.odr#9):

> If a local entity is odr-used in a scope in which it is not odr-usable, the program is ill-formed.

Notably, the rule says "if you odr-use it, it's ill-formed", not "if we can't determine whether it's an odr-use, it's ill-formed".

There is no odr-use of `x` in any specialization of that function call operator template.